# git cherry-pick branchless commit on remote

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to cherry pick a commit from github.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/469b750019adb193f2b973ab841ac87d0d06d4f2

As far as I can tell, it isn't a part of any active branches. I tried this in my local repo:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/angular/angular.js.git
git fetch upstream
git cherry-pick 469b750
```

I get this error

```
fatal: bad revision '469b750'
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I searched for lost, orphaned, and branchless commits, but I didn't find anything that helped. I could just copy/paste this and be done with it, but I'm trying to keep the history and learn more about git. Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to even fetch a commit from a remote that isn't reachable via a reference (which is a prerequisite to cherry-pick)

Comment: Most likely, the commit in question has become unreachable after a force-push (note that its parent, `80ea36256f8ffc6ad59ea5964c919c36327a909d`, is still reachable) but [somehow still shows up on Github](https://help.github.com/articles/commit-exists-on-github-but-not-in-my-local-clone/#the-branch-that-contained-the-commit-was-deleted).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will not be exactly cherry pick, but you can apply this commit as follows:

1. Add `.patch` to Github URL and save it as git patch file:

   ```
   wget https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/469b750019adb193f2b973ab841ac87d0d06d4f2.patch -o new.patch
   ```
2. Apply this commit to your tree with `git am`:

   ```
   git am new.patch
   ```

Outcome of this should be identical to cherry-picking.

Comment: Combined research and self-help info into your answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @BookOfGreg: it is well known that you can get git-formatted patches from Github by adding .patch to url. Also I often use `git format-patch -1`/`git am` combo instead of cherry-picking - I find it more convenient. That's why I proposed this as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

That's a really interesting problem. I was testing it locally myself and the commit doesn't appear in `reflog --all` so it is not only orphaned but it's not downloaded from Github on a pull, clone or fetch.
It may be a case that it's totally lost forever unless you download it manually and put it back in the tree.

https://help.github.com/articles/commit-exists-on-github-but-not-in-my-local-clone/

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I saw that github article in my research, it's solid. The lack of any information about cherry picking suggests that it's not possible. I want to see if stackoverflow agrees.

Comment: mvp's solution downloads it manually and puts it back in the tree so my background was correct but his actual mechanism to do this is the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in bitbucket for a specific commit a coworker did today and then went to my command line to cherry pick that commit (and a series of other commits) into another experimental git branch. I noticed I go this "fatal: bad revision '#######'" error.
Its because even though it was in bitbucket, it was not in my local git repo... I did a 'git pull' to get those commits, and then the cherry pick worked.
That might be the solution to most of the issues with this error Im guessing.